# Jquery Difficulties selecting the correct div for appending html

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a comment system using ajax.

HTML snippet :

```
<div class="ThreadComments">
    <div class="ActualComments">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="large-1 columns small-3" align="center">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=[img]" />
            </div>
            <div class="large-11 columns">
                <p class="speechBubbleSecondary"><strong class="commenter_name">George</strong>Comment text <span class="MRWlabel" MRW-data="">Img</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-1 columns small-3" align="center">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=[img]" />
        </div>
        <div class="large-11 columns">
            <textarea class="WP_commentator" style="resize: none; height: 35px; font-size: 12px; padding: 2px;" pi-data="<?= $post['post_id'] ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Foundation 5 thus the heavy mark-up , and I want when an user posts a comment to append it to the `ActualComments` div , the problem is I can't manage to select it , because there are more posts with the same mark-up.

This is my ajax function :

```
$('textarea.WP_commentator').focus(function () {

    $('textarea.WP_commentator').keydown(function (keycheckcode) {
        if (keycheckcode.keyCode == 13) {
            var commentText = $(this).val();
            var postId = $(this).attr('pi-data');
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "commentator",
                data: {
                    comment: commentText,
                    post_id: postId
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $('textarea.WP_commentator').val("");
                    append(html);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's your question????

Comment: why dontcha append(commentText) instead of append(html) ?

Comment: Also you might consider adding some post identification in the comment div, something like class="ActualComments comment-post-233"
or even count them when they load with $each(addClass(i);i++)

Comment: @C-linkNepal '..the problem is I can't manage to select it ..'

Comment: @user1576978 Because it needs html markup to look ok on the page, I am using Zend for post identification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache you variable and then use some [DOM navigation method](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

```
    var $this = $(this);
    var commentText = $this.val();
    var postId = $this.attr('pi-data');
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "commentator",
        data: {comment: commentText, post_id: postId},
        success: function(html) {
            $this.val("")
            .closest('.ThreadComments').find('.ActualComments').append(html);

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your focus function is redundant. You need to establish which element text is being entered into, and use that for relative DOM traversal. Something like this:

```
$('textarea.WP_commentator').keydown(function (keycheckcode) {

    var myElem = $(this);

    if (keycheckcode.keyCode == 13) {
        ...

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (html) {
                myElem.closest('.ActualCommentsSibling')
                    .siblings('.ActualComments').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I added a sibling element in there because `.ActualComments` isn't an ancestor element of `myElem`. You'd need to add an appropriate class to that element in your HTML.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that the focus function is not necessary, I chose Karl's answer because it works on the existing html markup

Answer (score -1):

something like

```
$( ".ActualComments" ).last().append()
```

Comment: possibly $( ".ActualComments" ).last().add()

Comment: You can't be sure that the last instance is the correct one.

Comment: prove to me it does not answer the question and i'll give a crap what you think.